# Can Scip solve MIP subject to matrix equations?

Tags: matrix, equation, scip

My questions concerns the Mixed integer programming (MIP) in Scip:
I have the following code:

```
    $\min trace(X)$
subject to
    $$(A+D)^TX+X(A+D)=I\\
    d_i \in \left\{0,1\right\} \mbox{ for } i=1,\ldots,n$$
where A is a n*n matrix and $D=diag(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is a diagonal matrix.
```

Since the matrix constraints are linear the equation can be transformed to a system of linear equations (via Kronecker product and vectorize operation), but this is limited to small n. Is it possible to solve the matrix equation directly with Scip? Is there a way to embed an external solver? Or do I have to write my own solver for the continuous lyapunov matrix equation?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the pip file format used for polynomial constraints and objective. See http://polip.zib.de/ and http://polip.zib.de/pipformat.php

You would have to do the matrix operations yourself or use ZIMPL

Answer (score 0):

Matrix equations cannot be handled in SCIP. You would need to transform them into linear equations. Also, all the data has to be loaded into an LP solver at some time and needs to be formulated as usual constraints here as well. So even if SCIP itself would be able to handle matrix equations you are sooner or later to required to expand the problem.